# User non Administer System on Apache Guacamole can access history tab?

Tags: tabs, guacamole

[image]
**Non Administer system User Permissions**

[image]
**History Tab not shown on Non Administer system User**

[image]
**History Tab shown on Administer system User**

How to mod User non Administer system can access History tab on Apache Guacamole?

I have modified the guacPageList.html file but nothing happens